# How to Simplify Repeated Code Through a Function or Loop in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, replace

I have developed this code in Python to pull minimum value, second smallest, third smallest, fourth smallest, fifth smallest, sixth smallest and seventh smallest values from a df1 and df2 for minimum and maximum values. The purpose of this code is to replace df1 values with df2 values.

The code works; however, a lot of this code is repeated over and over and I was wondering if any of you have any ideas on how to make this code run through a loop or function so that it is simplified and more elegant?

```
## df1
min_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(1).iloc[-1]
sec_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]
thrd_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(3).iloc[-1]
frth_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(4).iloc[-1]
fifth_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(5).iloc[-1]
six_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(6).iloc[-1]
svn_df1 = df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(7).iloc[-1]

min_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(1).iloc[-1]
sec_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]
thrd_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(3).iloc[-1]
frth_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(4).iloc[-1]
fifth_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(5).iloc[-1]
six_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(6).iloc[-1]
svn_df1_max = df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(7).iloc[-1]

## df2
min_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(1).iloc[-1]
sec_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]
thrd_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(3).iloc[-1]
frth_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(4).iloc[-1]
fifth_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(5).iloc[-1]
six_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(6).iloc[-1]
svn_df2 = df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(7).iloc[-1]

min_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(1).iloc[-1]
sec_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]
thrd_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(3).iloc[-1]
frth_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(4).iloc[-1]
fifth_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(5).iloc[-1]
six_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(6).iloc[-1]
svn_df2_max = df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(7).iloc[-1]

# Replacing df1 values with df2

df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(min_df1, min_df2, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(sec_df1, sec_df2, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(thrd_df1, thrd_df2, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(frth_df1, frth_df2, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(fifth_df1, fifth_df2, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(six_df1, six_df2, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(svn_df1, svn_df2, inplace = True)

df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(min_df1_max, min_df2_max, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(sec_df1_max, sec_df2_max, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(thrd_df1_max, thrd_df2_max, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(frth_df1_max, frth_df2_max, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(fifth_df1_max, fifth_df2_max, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(six_df1_max, six_df2_max, inplace = True)
df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(svn_df1_max, svn_df2_max, inplace = True)

I have tried combining values to be replaced all at once but that didn't seem to work. I figured a loop would be a good idea but I am new to python and not sure where to start.
```

Comment: If you use a list instead of a bunch of variables like `min_df1`, `sec_df1`,..., `svn_df1` (so that items in the list can be accessed by an index number), it is much easier to see how each block can be written as a loop (or as list comprehension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lists` instead of multiple variables and a `for` loop to fill those lists. Once you have your lists filled you can use `zip` to replace df1 values with df2. Here is what that would look like:

```
# use lists instead of multiple variables
min_df1 = max_df1 = min_df2 = max_df2 = []
# Iterate from 1 to 7
for i in range(1, 8):
    # df1
    min_df1.append(
        df1['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(i).iloc[-1])
    
    max_df1.append(
        df1['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(i).iloc[-1])

    # df2
    min_df2.append(
        df2['value_bucket_min'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(i).iloc[-1])
    
    max_df2.append(
        df2['value_bucket_max'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(i).iloc[-1])

# Replacing df1 values with df2
for df1_min_val, df1_max_val, df2_min_val, df2_max_val in zip(min_df1, max_df1, min_df2, max_df2):
    df1['value_bucket_min'].replace(df1_min_val, df2_min_val, inplace=True)
    df1['value_bucket_max'].replace(df1_max_val, df2_max_val, inplace=True)
```